# Intel core (TM)2 Duo T5870 The host does not support Intel vt-x error while opening .Ovf

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, vmware-player

I am trying to open Hortonworks Sandbox 1.3 using VMware...

> Error: the virtual machine is configured for 64bit guest os. However 64bit operation is not possible.
>   The host does not support Intel vt-x

My environment:

```
Intel core(TM)2 Duo T5870 @ 2.00GHz
2Gb ram
64bit os Windows 7
```

I checked in bios but no virtualization option in system configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your processor does not support VTX, check the processor specifications. Under Advanced Technologies "Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x) ".

[T5870 Specs](http://ark.intel.com/products/37034/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T5870-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB)

Comment: Thanks TheCreator232 recently I 'll buy a laptop  I 'll check and buy.

Comment: Is there any alternative to this ? Please say